Flutter Flame Game: Character Stays in 'up' Position After Restarting Game
I am developing a game using Flutter and Flame. In my game, the character has two states: middle and up. The character moves to the up state when the user initiates a jump and returns to the middle state after a delay.
The problem I am facing is that when the game ends due to a collision while the character is in the up state, and I restart the game, the character continues from the up state instead of resetting to the middle state.
Here is my code:
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flame/collisions.dart';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/effects.dart';
import 'package:flame_audio/flame_audio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:rungame/game/assets.dart';
import 'package:rungame/game/configuration.dart';
import 'package:rungame/game/skateboardera_girl.dart';
import 'package:rungame/game/skater_girl_movement.dart';

class SkaterGirl extends SpriteGroupComponent<SkaterGirlMovement>
    with HasGameRef<skateboarderGirl>, CollisionCallbacks {
  SkaterGirl();
  int score = 0;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final skaterGirlCharacter = await gameRef.loadSprite(Assets.skatergirl);
    final skaterGirlCharacterUp = await gameRef.loadSprite(Assets.skatergirlUp);
    FlameAudio.audioCache
        .loadAll([Assets.flying, Assets.collision, Assets.point]);

    size = Vector2(120, 120);
    double bottomPadding = 190;
    position = Vector2(120, gameRef.size.y - size.y - bottomPadding);

    current = SkaterGirlMovement.middle;
    sprites = {
      SkaterGirlMovement.middle: skaterGirlCharacter,
      SkaterGirlMovement.up: skaterGirlCharacterUp,
    };

    add(RectangleHitbox());
  }

  void fly() {
    if (current != SkaterGirlMovement.up && !gameRef.isHit) {
      try {
        FlameAudio.play(Assets.flying);
        debugPrint('çaldı canım');
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint('Error playing audio: $e');
      }
      add(
        MoveByEffect(
          Vector2(0, Config.gravity),
          EffectController(duration: 0.5, curve: Curves.decelerate),
          onComplete: () {
            if (current != SkaterGirlMovement.up && !gameRef.isHit) {
              current = SkaterGirlMovement.up;
              debugPrint('if up tan sonra ki ');
              Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {
                if (!gameRef.isHit) {
                  debugPrint("if game is hit -->  ${game.isHit}");
                  resetPosition();
                  current = SkaterGirlMovement.middle;
                  gameRef.skatergirl.score++;
                  try {
                    FlameAudio.play(Assets.point);
                    debugPrint('çaldı point');
                  } catch (e) {
                    debugPrint('Error playing audio: $e');
                  }
                  debugPrint("Score fly file: ${gameRef.skatergirl.score}");
                } else {
                  resetPosition();
                  return;
                }
              });
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    } else {
      debugPrint('Collision detected while flying, exiting fly function');
      current = SkaterGirlMovement.middle;
      return;
    }
  }

  void resetPosition() {
    debugPrint('reset position ');
    size = Vector2(120, 120);
    double bottomPadding = 190;
    position = Vector2(
      120,
      gameRef.size.y - size.y - bottomPadding,
    );
    current = SkaterGirlMovement.middle; // Orta pozisyon olarak ayarla
  }

  @override
  void onCollisionStart(
    Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints,
    PositionComponent other,
  ) {
    super.onCollisionStart(intersectionPoints, other);
    debugPrint('Collision detected ');

    gameOver();
  }

  void gameOver() {
    try {
      FlameAudio.play(Assets.collision);
      debugPrint('çaldı game over');
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error playing audio: $e');
    }

    gameRef.overlays.add('gameOver');
    gameRef.pauseEngine();
    game.isHit = true;
    resetPosition(); // Oyun bittiğinde karakteri orta pozisyona sıfırla

    debugPrint("game is hit -->  ${game.isHit}");
  }

  void reset() {
    gameRef.flowerGroup.resetFlowers();
    current = SkaterGirlMovement.middle;
    score = 0;
  }
}


I've tried to ensure that the character's position and state are reset to middle in both resetPosition() and reset(), but the issue persists. How can I ensure that the character always starts in the middle state when the game restarts?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

When you restart your game, completely recreate the player component instead of re-using the player component that you used for the last run. This will also remedy a bunch of possible future bugs if the player will keep some state.
